# Alice blue api module problem with Strategy Creation

Tags: python, import, strategy-pattern

```
from alice_blue import *
import pdb
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd

access_token = '1JekMg.ezoSy4HW8rn3zjUzpRWR2fA2P9c6yQLjGWHdnCvXtOs'
alice = AliceBlue(username='', password='', access_token= '5ENG1JekMg.ezoSy4HW8rn3zjUzpRWR2fA2P9c6yQLjGWHdnCvXtOs', master_contracts_to_download=['NSE', 'NFO'])




traded_stocks = []
socket_opened = False


def event_handler_quote_update(message):
    print(f"quote update {message}")

    name = message['instrument'].symbol
    openx = message['open']
    high = message['high']
    low = message['low']
    close = message['close']
    ltp = message['ltp']
    cap = 100000
    curr_time=datetime.datetime.now()
    crt_time=curr_time.time()
    breakout=datetime.time(18, 30)
    

    if (crt_time >= breakout) and (name not in traded_stocks) and (ltp >= high): 
        print(f"buy: {name} , ltp: {ltp}")
        traded_stocks.append(name)
        message = alice.place_order(transaction_type = TransactionType.Buy, instrument = alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', name), quantity = 1 , order_type = OrderType.Limit, product_type = ProductType.BracketOrder, price = high, trigger_price = None, stop_loss =low, square_off =float(format((high-low), ".1f")), trailing_sl = None, is_amo = False)
        sleep(10)
    else :
        print(f"time not satisfied is {curr_time}")
        
    
    
def open_callback():
    global socket_opened
    socket_opened = True

alice.start_websocket(subscribe_callback=event_handler_quote_update,
                    socket_open_callback=open_callback,
                    run_in_background=True)
while(socket_opened==False):
    pass

instrument = [alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', 'ICICIBANK')] 

while True:
    alice.subscribe(instrument, LiveFeedType.MARKET_DATA)
```

Im trying to code a Open Range Breakout Strategy with this alice(https://pypi.org/project/alice-blue/)

But i cant breakthrough what concept to use
Can anyone Suggest a CODE based on provided link to alice-blue data and code please

I tried of placing order on specific time alone but the code runs and fires orders continously
Want a Suggestion with Function and the Order must be placed only once for a certain script

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a cron job at 9:30 AM and Store the Highest Price in DB.

Step 2: Create another cron job for every 15 mins --> Compare LTP > High

Step 3: If the condition is true --> Place an order and store the order ID & instrument

Step 4: Create one more cron job for exit signal --> compare with Target or SL price ---> Place Exit Order